# TFS "Branch per Release" Branching design issue

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

Team, 
We are using a branching strategy called "Branch per release". For every Release we create a Branch and development, testing and deployment will be done from the same Release branch. After a successful PROD Deployment, we will merge the changes from Release branch to MAIN. So, Our MAIN is always PROD replica..

This plan worked very well, but only one thing is been an issue for us. When we have parallel development for different releases, how do we carry one release changes to other releases before it goes to production?

Sometimes, we are in a situation where we need to develop the next release on top of current development? SO, how do i solve this issue? ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional branch for stablization/integration.

- Main

  - Release 1.0
  - Release 2.0
  - Integration

    - Development

Let's say you have version 2.0 in production and you're preparing version 3.0.
Development for version 3.0 happens in Development. When you're ready to stabilize 3.0 for release, you merge it to integration. Additional work (bugfixes, etc) for 3.0 happens in integration. Changes are merged back up to Development on a daily basis.

Parallel development is then free to happen for version 4.0 in the Development branch.

Comment: Our main goal is to do parallel development. Let say, While V3.0 is in development, we want to start V4.0, V5.0 in parallel. But, its often happening a situation that we needed V3.0 changes in V4.0 and V5.0 before V3.0 goes to live. How do we get V3.0 Changes in V4.0 & V5.0 ? i see only option to do baseless merge which i hate it.

Comment: @haribabu In the example I provided, Development is branched off of Integration. There is no baseless merge.